# Removing empty words in a list in R

Tags: r, regex, lapply

I have a long list of words, some of which are empty strings. This is part of the list.

```
17`[[95]]
[1] "while"     ""          "however"   ""          "the"       "right"                 "is"        "unsettled"
[9] ""          "we"        "have"      "avoided"   "changing"  "the"          "state"

17`[[96]]
[1] "of"            "things"        "by"            "taking"        "new"            "posts"        
[7] "or"            "strengthening" "ourselves"     "in"            "the"           "disputed"
```

I'm trying to get rid of the empty strings in each element of the list. I don't know how to do this using regular expressions, and can't figure why the following lapply doesn't work either:

```
new_list = lapply(list, function(x) x = x[x != ""])
```

Can you help correct the code? Also, do you know how to use regexp for that? Thanks.

Comment: You need to return the changed `x` object - `lapply(L, function(x) {x <- x[x != ""]; x} )` Using `regex` to search for an empty object seems like overkill to me.

Comment: @thelatemail didn't work. It's the same output as before. What if each element I printed above is a list itself? ie this is a list of lists. Could this be the problem?

Comment: This is why providing a reproducible example is helpful. Is your data something like `L <- list(list(c("one", "", "two")), list(c("", "here", "it is")))` ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. For when I type class(list[[23]]) I get "list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
lapply(list, function(x) lapply(x, grep, pattern = "^$", value = TRUE, invert = TRUE))
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned the recursive apply (`rapply`) can be used

```
rapply(list, grep, pattern = "^$", value = TRUE, invert= TRUE, how = "list")
```

Comment: Didn't work. It's the same output as before. What if each element I printed above is a list itself? ie this is a list of lists. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @Ali That could be the case.  Otherwise, it should work

Comment: Maybe `rapply(..., how="list")` ?

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks. If you write it as a post I will definitely upvote it.